# Add All Routes in ./routes to Middleware Stack

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Right now I am using `app.use()` and `require()` for each route in my routes directory to add them to the middleware stack (I am using Express).

```
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));
app.use('/post', require('./routes/post'));
app.use('/submitPost', require('./routes/submitPost'));
...
```

Instead of doing this manually for each file, I would like to use a for-loop to iterate through the route files in ./routes and add each file to the middleware stack. This is what I have, but it isn't working:

```
require('fs').readdir('/routes', function (err, files) {
    if (!err) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i].substr(files[i].lastIndexOf('.'));
            app.use('/' + file, require('./routes/' + file));
        }
    }
});
```

Could someone help me correct this bit of code. On another note, are there any disadvantages to automatically adding all routes in ./routes to the middleware stack?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have done something similar, not exactly for express routes, but it should work correctly. I'd say your problem is sync problem. You're probably starting the server before adding routes (I'm not sure if it works correclty that way). readdir is an async operation, so whatever is after that block of code, it will probably execute before what's inside that block.

Comment: @Tiago So should I try [```fs.readdirSync()```](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is probably *when* you are adding the middleware. You are using `readdir` - the asynchronous method. You likely have a catch-all 404 handler declared after your code, and as the routes you are requiring are added asynchronously, they will probably be added after the catch-all. When the request propagates through the middleware, this would terminate it before it even got to the route.

One other issue is the path you are using: `/routes` will attempt to look in the route of your filesystem. `./routes` or `__dirname + '/routes'` is probaby what you want.

The following code sample works for me:

```
var files = require('fs').readdirSync('./routes')  
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i].substr(0, files[i].lastIndexOf('.'));
    app.use('/' + file, require('./routes/' + file));
}
```

Comment: Oh, just saw @Tiago's answer above... which is pretty much what I thought later! One other issue is that your substr looks incorrect - but maybe it works for you? Mine assumes routes are `/routes/users.js` etc.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, you can use [file-manifest](https://github.com/mantacode/file-manifest) for this. It was actually created specifically for this use case, although it still expects you to call `app.use` yourself, since order matters for express routes.

So you can do something like:

```
var fm = require('file-manifest');
var routes = fm.generate('./routes');
app.use('/', routes.home);
app.use('/foo', routes.foo);
// etc.
```

If you *really* want it to all happen magically, you could make that work with a custom reduce function, but this is much more explicit and ensures that routes are set up in the right order (so you don't end up with `/foo` falling before `/foo/bar` and preventing it from being reached).

I believe I am supposed to qualify that I wrote this library.

Comment: That's an interesting little package. I'd rather not install another dependency for such a trivial task though, sorry. Thanks for alerting me about the order of how I ```app.use()``` the routes; I don't think that will be an issue though, as I'm using separate [```express.Router```](http://expressjs.com/api.html#router)s for each route, which includes any children of that branch.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.  Here's a clean implentation using the basic fs and path modules.

```
var fs = require("fs"),
    path = require("path");

var root = "./routes/"

fs.readdir(root, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    files.forEach(function (file) {
        var filename = file.slice(0, -3);
        var routePath = '/' + ((filename === 'index') ? '' : filename);  //filter index to use just '/'
        app.use(routepath, require(root + filename));
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice use of the ternary operator to check for index! I didn't even think about replacing ```'index'``` with ```''```.